# How to know cookie property in android webkit

Tags: java, android, cookies, webkit, cookiemanager

I used android.webkit.CookieManager.

I want to get all data about cookie.

But I got only cookie's name and value.

How do I get expires or other data.

Especially, I need expires of cookies.

Thank you.

Here is My Code

```
public void updateCookie(String url) {
    String allCookie = null;
    String[] cookies = null;
    String cookieNameTmp = null;
    String cookieContetTmp = null;
    cookieNames.clear();
    cookieValue.clear();

    if(!m_adapter.isEmpty()) {
        m_adapter.clear();
    }
    try {
        allCookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        if(allCookie != null) {
            allCookie = allCookie.replace(" ", "");
            cookies = allCookie.split(";");
            for (String cookie : cookies) {
                cookieNameTmp = cookie.split("=")[0];
                m_adapter.add(cookieNameTmp);
                cookieContetTmp = cookie.replace(cookieNameTmp+"=", "");
                cookieNames.add(cookieNameTmp);
                cookieValue.add(cookieContetTmp);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("updateCookie: ", e.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Start by sharing the code you're using to get the cookies name and values.

Comment: ok I have shared now. That code just store name and value. My hope is saving expires.